# Long logical operator comparisons

Tags: php, if-statement, logical-operators, comparison-operators

I have three variables which determine an outcome. There is only two outcomes but the outcome is based on the variables. I have thought up some long if statements but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it.

```
$loggedin = (0 or 1) // If it is 0 then one outcome if 1 then it falls onto the next three variables
$status = (0-5) // 4 dead ends
$access = (0-3) // 
$permission = (0-9)
```

Different combinations of the last two variables result in different outcomes, although some combinations are irrelevant as they are dead ends.

```
if ($loggedin == 1 && ($status == 1 || $status == 2 ) &&  'whattodohere' ):
```

I could type all of the combinations manually `($access == 0 && ($var == 2 || $var = 6))` but I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at  `bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Also take a look at range(...) - http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

$status == 1 || $status == 2 [... $status == n] can be reduced to in_array( $status, range(0, $n) )

Using in_array & range is more costly performance-wise tho, so if you're dead sure you only need to try against 2 different values, use == operator instead.

Answer (score 1):

An approach could to be to use switch(): http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Example:

```
<?php
/*
$loggedin = (0 or 1) // If it is 0 then one outcome if 1 then it falls onto the next three variables
$status = (0-5) // 4 dead ends
$access = (0-3) // 
$permission = (0-9) */

$access = 1;
$loggedin = 1;
$status = 1;

if ($loggedin == 1) {
 if ($status == 1 || $status == 2 ) {
        switch($access) {
            case 0:
            //do some coding
            break;

            case 1:
            echo 'ACCESSS 1';
            //do some coding
            break;

            default:
            //Do some coding here when $access is issued in the cases above
            break;
        }
    }
}
else {
    //Do coding when $loggedIn = 0
} 

?>
```

In the example ACCESS 1 would be the output.

Maybe you could also do some math and compare the result (in some circumstances depending on what you want to achieve). For example:

```
<?php
$permission = 1;
$access = 2;
$result = $permission * $access;
if ($result > 0) {
    switch($result) {
        case 0:
        //do something
        break;
        case 1:
        //do something
        break;
        default:
        //Do something when value of $result not issued in the cases above
    }
}
?>
```